# How to highlight own keywords in HTML lstlistings?

Tags: listings, highlighting, html, keywords

I would like to highlight some words in a `lstlisting`. The language is HTML.
However, `\emph` seems not to be working with HTML.
Any suggestions how I could work around this problem?

Right now I have:

```
\lstdefinestyle{htmlCode} {
language=html,
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
emph={time},
emphstyle=\color{green}
}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=htmlCode,caption={Html code}] 
<b>Time: $time$</b>
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Would you be able to post what you currently have, or at least a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)?

Comment: Ok, I have added sample code.

Comment: For information, the reason why `\emph` and `\emphstyle` have no effect seems to stem from the `tag` key, which is used in the definition of the `HTML` language (in `lstdrvrs.dtx`). If you redefine `HTML` without using that `tag` key, your custom identifiers will be highlighted as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `escapechar=<char>` option for `listings` in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
 \lstdefinestyle{htmlCode} {
   language=html,
   basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily,
   commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
   escapechar=| % Escape to LaTeX between |...|
}

 \begin{lstlisting}[style=htmlCode,caption={Html code}] 
<b>Time: $|\color{green}time|$</b>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Listings with escape character]

The reason for this working may involve the fact that `listings` allows escaping to LaTeX when using the `mathescape=true` flag. This escapes around `$...$`, which is exactly around your `time` "keyword".

Comment: Great, that's working.

Comment: I actually also want to capture the $ sign (unlike in the example). Could I use something like morecomment=[b]{\$} to format all sequences between the $ character?

Comment: @nrainer: You could use `|\color{green}\$time\$|`.