# Correctly highlighting custom html tags in listings

Tags: listings, highlighting, minted, html, code

## Problem statement

I have several code listings containing HTML markup in my latex files. These listings contain multiple custom html tags (created in combination with corresponding AngularJS directives).

Such an HTML fragment could look for example like this:

```html
<list-component data="angularDataObject"
    list-type="dataActor">
</list-component>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Originating from a CamelCase name of a directive `listComponent` in JavaScript, a dash is added in between resulting in `list-component` to maintain code readability.

I tried using both [listings](/questions/tagged/listings) and [minted](/questions/tagged/minted) for syntax highlighting:

### listings

Using [listings](/questions/tagged/listings) I achieved the following result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML]
<list-component data="angularDataObject"
    list-type="dataActor">
</list-component>
<div id="test"></div>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: listings result]

As you can see, the tag name is not identified, neither the custom attribute `list-type`. I think the word `type` is recognized as standard html attribute and therefore highlighted.

### minted

Using [minted](/questions/tagged/minted) I achieved the following result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{html}
<list-component data="angularDataObject"
    list-type="dataActor">
</list-component>
<div id="test"></div>
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image: minted result]

The minted result is even worse, as the word `list` is highlighted before the dash - `component` by contrast isn't, even though `list` is not an HTML standard tag. Attributes look fine this time, but the closing tag is not identified at all and gets an ugly background behind the opening bracket `<`.

## My goal

I search for a plugin that is able to automaticly detect and highlight custom tags, without needing to add them each by each - since I might be unsure which tags I'll use in the future. Further it would be great to identify custom attributes, but I could go without that, if attributes are not highlighted at all.
Finally it is essential that closing tags are at least highlighted the same way as the opening ones were highlighted before.

Thanks in advance for your generous help and advices!

By the way, while typing this question and adding language data for different code highlighting I discovered that Google Code prettifier is analyzing and displaying my code perfectly :-/

## Other related TEX.SE questions

**[\listings code style for HTML5 (CSS, HTML, JavaScript)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99500/54024)**
In this solution any tags must be noted in the settings in order to be identified.

**[How to highlight own keywords in HTML lstlistings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26371/54024)**
This solution allows individual highlighting of code parts, but changes need to be hard-coded into the listing. This ruins readability in the TEX markup.

**[How to use angle brackets for a keyword in \listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99622/54024)**
This solution reuires once again that all tags are defined a priori.

Comment: could you provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to simplify testing?
that said, the `listings` package does allow for additional, manually specified, keywords.. see section 3 of [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)

Comment: @greyshade I updated both latex lsitings to form MWEs - sorry I missed `documentclass` and document-begin/-end before. The minted example is not totaly minimal, as the style definition is not needed, but as I already used `borland` for the screenshot, I would stick with that. The HTML markup contains all required items and for comparison a standrad div-tag with an attribute.

Your suggested solution, by adding tags to [tag:listings]is already covered within two of the three referenced questions and is not exactly what I try to achieve. Nonetheless thanks for your idea! =)

Comment: This should definitely work in minted; there seems to be a bug in [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), which is used internally by minted – you should [submit a bug report](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues?status=new&status=open) there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after some thinking about how to do this with `listings` while avoiding manually specifying keywords, I suppose a syntax based solution may work.

I.e. I defined a language for `listings` using `moredelim` and `morestring` to handle the most basic syntax of `XML` and get the following results:
[image]

the corresponding code is:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML_SYNTAX}{%
    alsoletter=-,
    morestring=[b]",stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
    moredelim=*[s][{\color[rgb]{0.75,0,0}}]{<}{>},
    moredelim=[s][{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}]{<!--}{-->},
    moredelim=[s][{\color[rgb]{0,0.75,0}}]{\ }{=},
    moredelim=[s][{\color[rgb]{0,0.75,0}}]{\    }{=} % here there is \tab
}

\lstset{
    % Basic design
    backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9},
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    breaklines=true,
    frame=l,
    tabsize=2,
    % Line numbers
    xleftmargin={0.75cm},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
    % HTML formatting
    language=XML_SYNTAX,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
<!-- with tab -->
<list-component data="angularDataObject"
    list-type="dataActor">
</list-component>
<!-- with space -->
<list-component data="angularDataObject"
  list-type="dataActor">
</list-component>
<!-- some other tag -->
<div id="test"></div>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

For explanation of what the the code does, refer to sections 3.2, 3.3 and 4.18 onwards of [the `listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

<strike>Note: for some reason the `list-type` attribute is still wrong, although I told `listings` to treat `-` as a letter with `alsoletter={-}` - maybe you can figure out why that is, otherwise I'll have some time for more testing in a few hours.</strike>

<strike>This was due to my usage of a tab for indentation, rather than a space. As that is fixed now, more debugging to do, since the closing `>` of the `list-component` tag has now become green as well..</strike>

Thanks to @Jubobs this is fixed as well - it was my bad to have an extra `*` in the attribute style line. In addition I fixed things to that indentation with tabs also works.

Comment: Remove the star in the last `moredelim`; then the closing `>` will be in the correct colour.

Comment: Great solution, I didn't even think of considering xml. That happens if you rush into a problem, instead of stepping back and seeing (the more or less simple solution) Thanks!

Comment: How come if a line gets intended the element turns green?

Comment: @kojow7 this may be to do with having `\tab` and `\space` as a delimiter in the last two rows of the `\lstdefinelanguage{XML_SYNTAX}` - to really figure what's happening, you might need to be more specific though: can you give an example where it leads to incorrect highlighting?