# How to put some commands written by a software's codes into Latex beamer?

Tags: beamer

I prepared a program written in GAP's envirounment. I'd like to put them all in one of my beamer pages exactly as follows:

```
gap> z:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,10);; n:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,15);;
     s:=DirectProduct( z, n );;
     e:=Elements(s);;
     r:=Filtered(e,t->Order(t)=10);;
     Size(r);;
```

What can I do? I used `\text{}` to get the result as it is shown above but it's useless. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may want to have a look at the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or `minted` packages.

Comment: Make sure you use the `[fragile]` option for the frame containing the verbatim text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wish to look into the [`listings`](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package which was designed for exactly that task.

A minimal example would look like so:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Example with listings}
    Code can be included and formatted with the \lstinline{listings} package:
    \begin{lstlisting}
gap> z:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,10);; n:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,15);;
     s:=DirectProduct( z, n );;
     e:=Elements(s);;
     r:=Filtered(e,t->Order(t)=10);;
     Size(r);;
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and produce this output:
[image: basic output]

`listings` comes with a host of formatting options, including line breaking, font size and selection as well as syntax based highlighting of code - see the [package documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) as well as these answers here on TeX.SX: [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199058/problems-with-xml-syntax-highlighting/199083#199083), [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195414/correctly-highlighting-custom-html-tags-in-listings/195450#195450).