# Adding programing code on LaTeX

Tags: code

I need to put some code from Linux's configuration files and some JavaScript in a document. I have tried to use `\texttt`, it worked for some Linux's basic commands like `sudo apt-get install XYZ`, but the code that I need to insert have `#` for comments and `$` for variables.

Is there some special tag for this?

Here some example of the code that I need to paste in document:

JavaScript:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev', // Endereço do banco de dados mongodb com a porta padrão
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId', //Identificação da aplicação
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here$ //Chave secreta para o aplicativo se conectar ao servidor
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',$
  //URL que vai estar disponível após o parse-server iniciar
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support f$
  }
```

Configuration File:

```
# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Adiciona o HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name app.example.com;
}
```

I'm using ShareLatex. I don't know if it can make any difference on this part.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to do but if you just want to insert code into a latex document then I recommend using the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. The documentation is very readable and there are multiple examples on TeX.SX. Another alternative is [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted).

Comment: Related: [Print programs with its proper syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax), [\listings code style for HTML5 (CSS, HTML, JavaScript)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99500/listings-code-style-for-html5-css-html-javascript), [Correctly highlighting custom html tags in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195414/correctly-highlighting-custom-html-tags-in-listings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `listings` package.  Unfortunately, there are no syntax highlighting patterns for Javascript in `listings`.

Because most of the lines in your code are too wide for the page you should apply my solution for [lstlisting line wrapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116572/10995).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\color{red}$\hookrightarrow$\space}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev', // Endereço do banco de dados mongodb com a porta padrão
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId', //Identificação da aplicação
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here$ //Chave secreta para o aplicativo se conectar ao servidor
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',$
  //URL que vai estar disponível após o parse-server iniciar
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support f$
  }
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Adiciona o HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name app.example.com;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]